# How to implement a codependency?

Tags: alloy

I am creating an Alloy model of the iCalendar data format.

An iCalendar file contains one or more objects. Each object contains properties and components.

```
sig iCalendarObject {
    obj_properties: set Property,
    components: set Component
}
```

Each object may optionally have a method property.

```
sig iCalendarObject {
    obj_properties: set Property,
    components: set Component
} {
    lone prop: method | prop in obj_properties
}
```

Each component contains properties.

```
abstract sig Component {
    comp_properties: set Property
}
```

vevent is one type of component.

```
sig vevent extends Component {}
```

vevent may optionally have a dtstart property.

```
sig vevent extends Component {}
{
    lone prop: dtstart | prop in comp_properties 
}
```

If an object does not have a method property (recall that method is optional), then any vevent component within the object *must* have a dtstart property.

So, there is a codependency between the method property in an object and the dtstart property in a vevent component within the object.

```
sig iCalendarObject {
    obj_properties: set Property,
    components: set Component
} {
    lone prop: method | prop in obj_properties
    // VEVENT must have DTSTART if no METHOD in object
    no prop_method: method | prop_method in obj_properties =>
        all comp: components {
           comp in vevent
           one prop_dtstart: dtstart | 
              prop_dtstart in comp.comp_properties
       }
}
```

Unfortunately, that model doesn't do what I want it to do.

When the Alloy Analyzer generates instances, the codependency is ignored. That is, the instance shows an object that does not have a method property and a vevent component within the object, but the vevent component does not have the required dtstart property.

This has me stumped. Would you help, please?

**Update**: I found the solution. I simply needed parentheses:

```
(no prop_method: method | prop_method in obj_properties) =>
```

With that small change, the codependency now behaves as expected.

It seems that `no` has a greater reach than I was aware of.